# Correct way to put conditional formatting on a UITableViewCell depending on its contents?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm pulling in some objects via Core Data and an `NSFetchedResultsController` and I'm trying to apply conditional formatting to them based on one of their boolean properties. If they're marked as `Liked` I want their text colour to be blue, for example.

The issue I'm finding is that upon scrolling the table, more than just those with `Liked` as `YES` are being coloured. It's a regular pattern too, for example every sixth entry as I scroll down. I think it's something to do with cell queueing and re-use, but I have no idea what. Here's my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath: indexPath];

    Quote *thisQuote = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 4;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 12];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: indexPath] quote];

    if ([[thisQuote isLiked] boolValue]) {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`, you have to reset the property textColor for every cell :

```
if ([[thisQuote isLiked] boolValue]) {
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
else cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: That made no difference at all.

Comment: Scratch that, yes it did, was accessing an NSNumber, not its boolValue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

For every sixth cell, you can always do:

```
if(indexPath.row % 6 == 0) {
    // Set blue color
}
else {
   // Set black color
}
```

or easier:

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = (indexPath.row % 6 == 0) ? [UIColor blueColor] : [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: I don't want every sixth cell, that's what's happening now, I want only those with the bool as YES to be coloured.